# JavaScript heap out of memory error was thrown in a Nuxt project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt porject ("nuxt": "^2.10.1") utilized vuetify2 ( "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.9.0"); More often than not, build takes at least 2 minutes and a lot of times during build or after that during watch specifically, the process crashes with this error:

"heap limit allocation failed - javascript heap out of memory"

And one report.json file would generated, and [this is the last one](https://filebin.net/a24rvdopepesw2hw/report.20200104.102942.4628.0.001.json?t=pi5k92yx).

I've tried to increase memory limit of node.js and nuxt within the config (my system has 16GB RAM). 
Some say, there should be a package causing this problem such as prettify in a nuxt project and I changed the nuxt.config to disable it.

I have this frustrating problem over one month and tried almost every solution suggested on the Internet.

To some level, it seems to me that after upgrading to vuetify2, the issue have been raised.

These are [package.json](https://filebin.net/tzxihzeixc70swvy/package.json?t=mnx5v8ci) and [nuxt.config.ts](https://filebin.net/tzxihzeixc70swvy/nuxt.config.ts?t=u1wh0bkw).

My question is: Where does this problem root in? and how can I find it to solve it? 
How can I find that this problem is related to node.js or vue.js or nuxt.js or vuetify or another athird-party module? (because I did try to remove some node modules to investigate the problem)

Comment: I seem to be having the exact same problem, have you found anything else so far? The weird this is that the exact same project runs fine on my work laptop, but not my home computer.

Comment: @JasonLandbridge I added this config in package.json `"scripts": { "dev": "nuxt-ts --max-old-space-size=8188",}}` ; it seems crashing occurs less than before. I've changed my system entirely with my colleague except for the hard disk, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those whose having this exact issue, you should disable the sourcemap from your nuxt config:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  sourcemap: false,
}
```